# HTML unordered list sucks in IE7

Tags: html, css

I've created a HTML ordered list which looks fine in FF, but pretty awful in IE.
My specific problems with the way IE displays the list are:

1. List markers are missing
2. Vertical spacing between list items is very uneven

It seems the superscripts are the cause of (2), but I'm not sure how I can fix this problem (without removing the superscripts).

**EDIT:** I gave up on my single-list dreams and split the list into 3 separate lists. I've removed the link from the text above to avoid confusing future readers.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: I'm using IE7 and your site looks fine. Maybe there is a bug in the FR version of IE7? Perhaps you have different default fonts? If I sort this out will you take me hunting? :)

Comment: @crescentfresh: see i told you we needed the code

Comment: Your spacing is uneven because of the super-script it forces the upper bounds of the text to be larger.

Comment: @Peter - I'm not a hunter myself, but if you sort this out and buy yourself a ticket to Quebec, I'll gladly find someone to take you hunting :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug of IE5, IE6, and still in IE 7.

IE 8 Beta 2 and the latest, IE 8 RC1, will display your web page correctly.

But these are a list of list item bug before IE 8:

http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/

http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/gaps/white-space-bug.php

Comment: While both true and informative, this is not useful. Can you imagine "Designed for IE8 except some bits which aren't"

Answer (score 2):

If it's the list at the bottom of the page, you've got a bunch of whitespace inside your list tags.  I don't know if that's causing the problem, but you might want to try eliminating it and see if that helps.  The superscripts may also be throwing things off.  Try giving the list itself a line height of 2em (or more) and see if that evens things out.

**EDIT**: you might also want to play with the left padding/margin on the list items and increase it to see if that brings the list markers back.  I've had to do this with list-based menus to get my menu items to show up in the proper alignment.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell for certain that the superscripts are what's altering the line height. If you want to force regular line heights you'll have to wrap everything in a table to prevent flow-based layount.

Comment: Hmm, tvan's idea of specifying a line height for LI elements in your stylesheet might well work, and it's a much better idea than a table. Treat the table suggestion as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

can you set the height of the li elments to account for the superscript?  probably best to do that in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned the height is due to the superscripted text.

As for the bullets Floating a list-item doesn't work well in IE.  If you plan on doing a three column layout try something like this.

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {  
  float:left;
  padding:2em;
  width:14em;
}
</style>

<ul>
 <li>col1 - item1</li>
 <li>col1 - item2</li>
 <li>col1 - item3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>col2 - item1</li>
 <li>col2 - item2</li>
 <li>col2 - item3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>col3 - item1</li>
 <li>col3 - item2</li>
 <li>col3 - item3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might see if the bullets are disappearing because you're coupling float-left with padding - not sure how IE counts the bullets as part of the size calcs.

Comment: I've changed that weird markup, doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: @crescentfresh: Thanks. :) It's great to be downvoted when trying to help. ;)

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted him! Any particular reason why you thought it was?

Comment: @Don: Another suggestion would be to just use three divs and a separate UL in each; floating the divs as opposed to the LIs.

Comment: True, but a single list is easier to maintain. I might try that if I can't get it working in a single list

Comment: @Don: woops! Sorry, his vote went negative around the same time you posted your "doesn't work" comment.

Comment: @Don, marginally easier to maintain, but looks like a pretty static page anyway, no? Either way you'll have a solution at hand, though.

Comment: It is static, but from a semantic POV a single list is also better. However, I'm pretty close to giving up on my single list dreams :)

Answer (score 0):

try doing this for your LI's

```
<li>text</li><li>text</li><li>text</li><li>text</li><li>text</li><li>text</li>
```

Don't add in any line breaks. It's silly that this might fix it, but it's true.